# How to solve "duplicate symbol" when added Firebase in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, firebase

I can't solve the error "duplicate symbol".

The error is

```
duplicate symbol _GSDK_NSClassFromString in: .../Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(overload_9ea29fd47bf44ee000bc4282b65dac06.o)
 /Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)

duplicate symbol _GSDK_objc_getClass in: .../Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(overload_9ea29fd47bf44ee000bc4282b65dac06.o)
/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)

duplicate symbol _GSDK_objc_getProtocol in:    ...Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(overload_9ea29fd47bf44ee000bc4282b65dac06.o)
    .../Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)

duplicate symbol _GSDK_objc_lookUpClass in:        ...Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore(overload_9ea29fd47bf44ee000bc4282b65dac06.o)
    ...Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)

ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I updated and installed Podfile. But it didn't work.

**Pod file**

```
target 'game' do

  # Pods for game
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
end
```

I could add Firebase before. But when I accidentally delete "FirebaseCore.framework".
After that I deleted Pods and reinstalled Firebase, but it didn't work.

How can I solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem here, since Firebase 3.4.7

Comment: Your project contain same file which is in firebase pod .. so you delete same file in Build Phase file manually.

Comment: I couldn't find same file in Build Phase. Even if I re-installed and updated firebase, the same error caused.

Comment: same problem with me too, anything progress, happened when i upgraded to 3.4.7

Comment: Ok, I think it may be some kind of bug in the Firebase 3.12.0, because when I downgraded to Firebase 3.11.0 all is fine, either a bug or some kind of project configuration that I am missing.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer.  I hope it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. It seems that the -all_load flag in the Other Linker Flags is causing this.

Answer (score 2):

There was a Firebase build issue introduced in 3.11.1 that will be fixed in 3.13.0 that can cause the duplicate symbol problem. In the meantime, a workaround is to back up to Firebase 3.11.0, by annotating any Firebase subspecs in your podfile with an explicit version number, like :

```
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '3.11.0'
```

Comment: Is there anyplace we can track progress on that issue publicly other than this post?

Comment: @DesignatedNerd Firebase 3.13.0 was released today and should fix the duplicate symbol issue.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Do you know if this has been fixed in more recent versions?

Comment: @Gordonium Yes  - fixed in 3.13.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by

1. Deleting everything from my podfile and running pod install
2. Putting everything back in my podfile and running pod install

It's the only thing that worked for me.