# How to solve ""_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from" with Firebase in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I can't solve the error ""_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:" in Xcode when I added Firebase (ver.3.12.0).

I found the solution to add "$(inherited)" in Other Linker Flags and I did it, but it didn't work.

How can I solve it?

[image: image of Other Linker Flags]

**Update (Podfile)**
[image: podfile]

**Update2**
[image: updated Podfile]
The linker error is deleted. But if I import "Firebase" by using `#import "Firebase.h"` or `@import Firebase;` or `#import <Firebase/Firebase.h>`, the error `'Firebase.h' file not found` has occurred.

Comment: How you are adding fire base SDK in your app through cocoapod or manually ?

Comment: Through cocoapod. I wrote "pod 'Firebase' " and " 'pod Firebase/AdMob' " on Podfile.

Comment: can you post your .pod file here so we can get idea whats actually going wrong?

Comment: I added Podfile picture. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to chnage your POD file like this as per Google AdMob suggestted on fire base quick start

```
target 'BannerExample' do
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
end
```

it will Install all dependent SDK and will show pod install log like below :

> Analyzing dependencies
>
> Downloading dependencies
>
> Installing Firebase (3.12.0)
>
> Installing FirebaseAnalytics (3.6.0)
>
> Installing FirebaseCore (3.4.7)
>
> Installing FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
>
> Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.17.0)
>
> Installing GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2)
>
> Installing GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
>
> Installing GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.1)
>
> Generating Pods project
>
> Integrating client project

Reference Link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start

**Edit:**

Also do one more thing uncomment `use_frameworks!` it will resolve your problem.

Hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: I did same thing but the other error occurred.... It's same to this error:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41871033/how-to-solve-duplicate-symbol-when-added-firebase-in-xcode?noredirect=1#comment71129020_41871033

Comment: please check my updated answer and uncomment `use_frameworks!` line to get out from this issue.

Comment: Thanks to you, the linker error is deleted. But the other error "Firebase.h not found" has occurred... I updated my question, so please check it.

Comment: No, there isn't "Firebase.framework"... only "Firebase.h".

Comment: Can you post your u[dated POD file agin ? I think some problem with POD file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135236/discussion-between-codechanger-and-bao).